# Error in PSO code which is used to maximize a function which uses the neural network as the output

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, neural-network, genetic-algorithm, particle-swarm

I have created a neural network for my data which has 4 parameters as input and 1 output. I want to optimize the output with pso but I get an error while compiling the code. I use the model.predict as the objective function. I used this function for genetic algorithm and I didn't have any problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H5fG.jpg) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL8Ci.jpg)

I want to get the optimum points from pso